# Get an arbitrary file from a directory tree

Tags: python, file, operating-system, directory, performance

I'd like to get a path to an arbitrary text file (with *.txt* suffix) which is present somewhere in the directory tree. The file should not be hidden or in hidden directory.

I tried to write the code but it looks little cumbersome. How would you improve it to avoid useless steps?

```
def getSomeTextFile(rootDir):
  """Get the path to arbitrary text file under the rootDir"""
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    for f in files:
      path = os.path.join(root, f)                                        
      ext = path.split(".")[-1]
      if ext.lower() == "txt":
        # it shouldn't be hidden or in hidden directory
        if not "/." in path:
          return path               
  return "" # there isn't any text file
```

Comment: I might use [splitext](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) instead of splitting manually, but other than that, it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) instead of string manipulations.

```
import os, os.path, fnmatch

def find_files(root, pattern, exclude_hidden=True):
    """ Get the path to arbitrary .ext file under the root dir """
    for dir, _, files in os.walk(root):
        for f in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            path = os.path.join(dir, f)
            if '/.' not in path or not exclude_hidden:
                yield path
```

I've also rewritten the function to be more generic (and "pythonic"). To get just one pathname, call it like this:

```
 first_txt = next(find_files(some_dir, '*.txt'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `os.walk` (like in your example) is definitely a good start.

You can use `fnmatch` ([link to the docs here](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html)) to simplify the rest of the code.

E.g:

```
...
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
        print file
...
```